# Spring Reactor scheduler lock

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, project-reactor

Can any one explain why this code never ends (always throws TimeoutException), 3.0.7 and 3.1.0.M3 all the same ?
I thought remaining 4 threads will do their work piece-by-piece.

```
private static class Holder {
    private final int group, idx;

    Holder(int group, int idx) {
        this.group = group;
        this.idx = idx;
    }
}

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RxTest2.class);

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.parallel();
    final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();

    Flux.range(0, 8).flatMap(gi -> Flux.range(0, 30).map(i -> new Holder(gi, i)))
        .groupBy(h -> h.group)

        .parallel()
        .runOn(scheduler)

        .flatMap(chunk -> {

            log.debug("chunk {}", chunk.key());

            chunk
                .parallel()
                .runOn(scheduler)
                .flatMap(h -> {
                    log.debug("{} - {}", h.group, h.idx);
                    c.incrementAndGet();
                    return Mono.just(true);
                })
                .sequential()
                .blockLast();

            return Mono.just(true);
        })
        .sequential()
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .doOnTerminate(() -> log.debug("count: {}", c.get()))
        .blockLast();
}
```

if I split it to separate schedulers (Schedulers.newParallel("p1", 8), Schedulers.newParallel("p2")) - all is OK

Is there some special rule for counting number of threads for scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple parallel computations running on Schedulers.parallel() and they saturate the scheduler fully, so there are no threads left to process `.flatMap(chunk ->`. We have thread starvation situation here. Just remove inner `chunk.parallel`, there is no need to do that as computation is already parallel.

Comment: thanks for reply, and sorry for my long silence!

assume we set:

    ...
    final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.parallel(16);
    ...
     .parallel(8)
            .runOn(scheduler)
    ...
                    .parallel(4)
                    .runOn(scheduler)

situation still the same.


I think: first _parallel_ blocks 8 threads, other tasks can use remaining 8 threads. Inner tasks are short. And work should be finished fine.

I want to understand why I'm wrong. What may blocks remainig threads